# Send Firebase Auth user to component with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I build up my project with React Router and Firebase.
My Router looks like:

```
...

<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Header user={{ ...currentUser }} />
         <Route
            exact
            path="/profile"
            component={currentUser => (
               <Profile
                 {...currentUser}
                 user={currentUser}
                />
            )}
         />
...
```

If I send the `currentUser` as a prop (like in `Header`) it works and I can get all `attributes`. But if I send it through a `Route` I only get *undefined*. I think this happens because the component renders before firebase send the answer to my user request. But I don't know how to fix that or how to save my `currentUser` locally (I've tried saving it in my `Session Storage` but that's not a good implementation I guess).

I'm thankful for every help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage` to easily get data while user is logged in:

After user logs in:

```
localStorage.setItem("username", currentUser);
```

In the next page:

```
let name = localStorage.getItem("username");
console.log(name);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder if this is a save solution? Do you use this in production or just personal projects?

Comment: because its uncommon to pass user data through localStorage. In case of firebase the best way to solve this is to wrap everything up in a AuthProvider and handle it with state.

Comment: it is actually common to pass in localStorage